# Mounting AWS EBS volume when launching VM with Docker Machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-machine

I'm exploring using Docker and Docker Machine to simplify my workflow for spinning up environments in AWS to support data analysis and machine learning tasks. I've worked out most of the details but have two outstanding questions:

1) When launching a VM in AWS with Docker Machine, how do I specify an EBS volume to attach to that VM?

2) How do I map the EBS volume through to a path in the container running on the VM?

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

I found this writeup to be helpful: https://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2015/06/02/mounting-an-ebs-volume-to-docker-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

You can specify volumes to mount in your `dockerrun.aws.json` file. Make sure to also mount the volume in your dockerfile as well, with something like `VOLUME: ["/var/ebs/path"]`. That should take care of mounting the sotarge to a path in the container.

BTW [this](https://github.com/leg100/docker-ebs-attach) is a cool container for attaching an EBS volume to the instance.

Comment: I am not sure that `dockerrun.aws.json` applies here. The blog post describes how to do it with Elastic BeanStalk and its built-in support for Docker. I believe it is different when suing docker-machine to create an ordinary EC2 instance. But perhaps the docker-ebs-attach docker container is a possible solution. (Or running some commands manually on the EC2 instance after being created by docker-machine via ssh)